# Properly adjusting the height of a JDialog to screen size

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a JDialog and I am trying to adjust it to the size of the screen. I am using the `setPreferredSize` Method of the JDialog. Without me using the method, everything looks fine unless the screen is too narrow. Then the Dialog overlaps the screen at the bottom and I can't reach the button bar. So I want it to always adjust to 90% of the height of the screen if it is below a certain height. In the JDialog there is a JPanel with a GridBagLayout. If I use `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, (int) (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height * 0.9)));` before the `pack`-method, this happens: [Upper end of Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNXbm.png) [Lower end of Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVx27.png)
How do I properly limit the size of my Dialog with the layout still being intact?

Comment: Why don't you put the content into a scroll pane, choose a reasonable default size for the dialog and let users resize it if needed? Adjusting layout based on size might confuse users and be more complex than actually needed.

Comment: Currently the buttons get missing if resize it to a too low height by dragging the window

Comment: That reads like you don't use a layout manager at all which would already be a flaw in itself. However, it should work if you'd (properly) use a scroll pane.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). **BTW:** It seems you've asked 4 questions previously which received no answers. Perhaps it's time to reconsider how you ask questions.